# I am having an error creating a react app in my probably due to an issue in my react-scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have installed the npm create-react-app and was given the following error(shown below) when i tried to npm start as a trial. I am a beginner and i tried to delete my node modules, package.json and package-lock.jason and reinstalled them. I updated all the current dependencies and did an npm audit fix but the error persists. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Node version 12.14.1
create-react-app version 3.3.0
Windows 10

```
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pandh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-22T10_07_03_047Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running on your local machine ? (use `node -v` to find out).
Can you add all the steps you followed on your terminal?

Comment: I am using v12.14.1. I simply did a npm start and received the error. I tried to check to make sure all the packages were up to date and cleared my cache however the error still persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i managed to resolve the issue by
adding the default variables in your machines PATH:
 `C:\Windows\system32` 
 `C:\Windows`
 `C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`

any other paths can be added to the end. Remember to have the npm paths as well:
`C:\Program Files\nodejs`
`C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm`

I found this resolution here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8337

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand the problem, but you can try doing `npm init -y` and then `npx create-react-app app-name` and not install the command.

Comment: The problem is that when i try to npm start my app, i get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely, issue related to `react-scripts` not being installed globally or you have an old version installed.

I suggest doing these three steps:

1. `$ npm install -g react-scripts`
2. `$ rm -rf node_modules` to remove the existing modules.
3. `$ npm install` to re-install the project dependencies.

Comment: ok, try to do `npm i -g npm@latest` then do the above or better @Mohit Chandel's answer, this should, this should remove most issues related to packages and dependencies. and let me know if it work to update my answer.

Comment: @EkamSingh, can you update question with the node version your are using? run `node --version` in your terminal to get the output also for `create-react-app` version.

Comment: It is Node version 12.14.1 create-react-app version 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the node_modules directory and reinstalling again using 
`npm install`

and then `killall node`

then `npm start`

Most of the time this error occurs when there are more than one app is using the node server

You can also try it by changing the port

Create a **.env** file at your project root and specify the port number there. Like:

`PORT=3005`

If that doesn't work either that means you don't have the multiple apps running problem

Comment: I tried this but the error persists. Could you specify how i can identify other apps using the web server because i had used react in the past but had not used it in a long while so now i am wondering if files from my last use are the cause.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't resolve the error.